# U-EV with Windows 10 1909

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10, user-experience-virtualization

My organisation has made the leap from 1607 LTS to 1909 Enterprise and without changing any share permissions or GPO's, all custom made non microsoft U-EV templates have stopped working. The main one I am testing with is Chrome currently.

Things I have tried:

- I have changed the schema from 2013A to 2012 in line with the microsoft ones
- I have removed version numbers for the product
- I have rescanned chromes file and registry locations and recreated the U-EV template
- I have explicitly added the encoding line to the XML declaration
- I have checked with a basic microsoft application (notepad) that using the process tags works outside application tags

I reckon this is going to be permissions somewhere down the line but figuring out what is not easy at this stage.

Event viewer gives me cryptic information at best:

```
Error 1509 - An error occured in the ApplySettingsTemplateCatalogUtility
```

I can only guess this is part of the issue and there are no other warnings or errors to go with it...

Any ideas or recommendations would be great. I have read somewhere that due to chrome opening multiple instances it might be possible that U-EV is not attached to the right instance?

EDIT:

So I have found that SOME custom applications work fine still so this is looking more like a chrome U-EV issue.

This is the message I receive when it attempts to save ANYTHING for the chrome U-EV policy:

```
Changes to the user settings cannot upload to the settings storage location 
because an earlier error occurred while downloading the settings package for
the settings location template "GoogleChrome".
```

Comment: Gave up and set the user directory in the GPO to the roaming directory. Chrome now roams..